# Clarification needed about Scala variance and type bounds

Tags: scala, variance, type-bounds

I have a scala trait defined as follows:

```
trait AdvertisementDAO[A <: Advertisement] extends CrudRepository[A, Integer] {
...
```

I would like to be able to get **an instance of this DAO that would work for both subclasses of Advertisement or the base Advertisement class itself**. I am not sure how to achieve the desired effect.

Here is what I tried:

```
@Inject
var advertisementDAO: AdvertisementDAO[+Advertisement] = _
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to define the type parameter, A, of the trait, AdvertisementDAO, as covariant.  Below is a variant of the code example from the previous answer using the covariance annotation, +.

```
trait Advertisement {}

class AdvertisementImpl extends Advertisement{}

class CrudRepository[+A,B]  {}

trait AdvertisementDAO[+A <: Advertisement] extends CrudRepository[A, Integer] {}

class AdvertisementDAOImpl[+A <: Advertisement] extends AdvertisementDAO[A]{}

class AdvertisementDAOImpl2 extends AdvertisementDAO[AdvertisementImpl]{}

class AdvertisementDAOImpl3 extends AdvertisementDAO[Advertisement]{}

object Tester
{
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit =
  {
    var advertisementDAO: AdvertisementDAO[Advertisement] = null
    advertisementDAO = new AdvertisementDAOImpl
    advertisementDAO = new AdvertisementDAOImpl2 
    advertisementDAO = new AdvertisementDAOImpl3
  }
}
```

Another example of a covariant generic is scala.collection.immutable.List.  Defining a generic (class or trait) C as covariant means that C[S] is a subtype of C[T], if type S is a subtype of type T.  For instance, AdvertisementDAO[AdvertisementImpl] is a subtype of AdvertisementDAO[Advertisement] because AdvertisementImpl is a subtype Advertisement (since AdvertisementImpl extends Advertisement).  I published a [paper](http://people.cs.umass.edu/~jaltidor/variance_pldi11.pdf), which contains tutorial on variance as it occurs in many languages (e.g. Scala, C#, Java).  [Slides](http://people.cs.umass.edu/~jaltidor/variance_pldi11_slides.pdf) are also available for a quick overview.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot of combinations but I receive one which compile with scala 2.9.1

```
  var advertisementDAO: AdvertisementDAO[_ <:Advertisement] = _

  advertisementDAO = new AdvertisementDAOImpl

  advertisementDAO = new AdvertisementDAOImpl2 

  advertisementDAO = new AdvertisementDAOImpl3
```

My code:

```
trait Advertisement {}

class AdvertisementImpl extends Advertisement{}

class CrudRepository[A,B]  {}

trait AdvertisementDAO[ A <: Advertisement] extends CrudRepository[A, Integer] {}

class AdvertisementDAOImpl[A <: Advertisement] extends AdvertisementDAO[A]{}

class AdvertisementDAOImpl2 extends AdvertisementDAO[AdvertisementImpl]{}

class AdvertisementDAOImpl3 extends AdvertisementDAO[Advertisement]{}
```

Comment: Thanks Ajozwik, Advertisment is a JPA entity and not a trait. Crud repository is a Spring data interface. Do you know how to ensure that only the base Advertisement class or its subclasses can be used instead of any class as in here: `var advertisementDAO: AdvertisementDAO[_]`

Comment: Try `var advertisementDAO: AdvertisementDAO[_ <:Advertisement] = _`